# How to set up an array of objects to be in format { x: {Number}, y: {Number} }? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, concave-hull

I'm trying to use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concavehull
And I don't know how to assign an array in order to use it with ConcaveHull npm.

The documentation says 
"*all you have to do is pass an array of objects that conform to the { x: {Number}, y: {Number} } format*".

Is that something like this:

[{"x":-0.206792373176235,"y":51.4911165465815},                                {"x":-0.206792373176235,"y":51.4911165465815},{"x":-0.206792373176235,"y":51.4911165465815},{"x":-0.206792373176235,"y":51.4911165465815} ... ]

Comment: That wouldn't be an array; it would be an object.

Comment: Ok, so what should I use?

Comment: it clearly says *pass an array of objects*, did you read the doc fully? and what is your exact issue here?

Comment: I need to get coordinates from database an to process them with this concavehull npm module (this is node.js). It should return points that form concave hull. So how should I initialize this array of coordinates to be processed with concave hull algorithm?

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you are having problems with. Maybe a [tutorial about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects) helps?

Comment: What does this notation mean: "{ x: {Number}, y: {Number} }" ?

Comment: That means the API expects an object with two properties, x and y, both of which should hold number values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly it, based on what I read.

```
var j = [{x: 51.2, y: 34.3},
         {x: 52.2, y: 37.3}];

console.log(j[0].x); // 51.2
```